# How to filter data set based on values in one of the columns by Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataset like below. I want to perform a filtering process according to a specific value in one of the columns.

For example, this is the original dataset:

**Name**   ...  **Age**     ......      **Phone_Type**

Joun     ....  25  .........    iPhone

Alex  .....   20 .......       Samsung

Sam .....60       .......      Nokia

David ...30........   iPhone

......................................

I want to filter all records to show only the users who are using "**iPhone**" by Python.

The Result should be:

Joun     ....  25  .........    iPhone

David ...30........   iPhone

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select rows from a DataFrame based on values in a column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Joun','Alex','Sam','David'], 'Age': [25,20,60,30],'Phone_Type':['iPhone','Samsung','Nokia','iPhone']})
```

You should try:

`df.loc[df['Phone_Type'] == 'iPhone']`